# Why a java iterator can cause resource leak?

Tags: java, eclipse

The code below generates warning in eclipse:

```
@Override
public Iterator<String> getErrorUlrs(int pCrawlId) {
    String collectionName = "collectionName";
    // mongoDB is of type com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase
    MongoCollection<Document> c = mongoDB.getCollection(collectionName);

    Bson filter = Filters.not(eq("exploreStatus", "OK"));
    Bson projection = fields(include("url"), excludeId());
    FindIterable<Document> docs = c.find(filter).projection(projection).batchSize(1000);
    Iterator<Document> it = docs.iterator();

    return new Iterator<String>() {

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return it.hasNext();
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            Document doc = it.next();
            return doc.getString("url");
        }
    };

}
```

The warning message is : Potential resource leak: 'it' may not be closed at this location

The initial iterator is returned by mongo java API. The reason why I'm coding this is that I don't want to expose the mongo API.

Why does eclipse display this warning ? How to get rid of it ?

**EDIT**

I've posted the complete method.
As mentioned in first answers, the iterator is of type MongoCursor and I guess the leak comes from here as this class implements closable.

Comment: Could be that the iterator is associated with a Mongo connection/cursor.  When you return it, there's no guarantee that the caller will know to close the connection.  Maybe you can do better by instantiating the iterator and closing it in a single method scope instead of returning it.  Load the Documents into a Java List<Document>, close the iterator/connection, and return the List.  Just like JDBC - you don't keep database connections open.

Comment: Please provide a complete example. The given example does not compile and the type of `docs` is unknown. You get the _Potential resource leak_ warning because you have an _AutoCloseable_ and it's unknown whether it is closed or not. Better refactor your code to use try-with-resources, e.g. by providing a _forEachDoc_ method instead of a method that returns an _Iterator_.

Comment: Does `return docs.map(doc -> doc.getString("url")).iterator();` generate the same warning?

Comment: You might refactor your code to have a method `void forEachErrorUrl(int pCrawlId, Consumer<String> action)` that does not return the iterator, but instead calls `forEachRemaining(action)` on the iterator inside a `try (Iterator<Document> it = docs.iterator()) { ... }`. This way the `MongoCursor` is guaranteed to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Since your iterator extends `Closable` interface, it requires closing when there are no more elements. So you have 2 options:

- Surround iterator actions with try-with-resources block
- Use `cursor.close()` in case `cursor.hasNext()` is false.